# how to only show field is required when input field is touched or clicked in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

When the getStarted function is called it will determine the condition if is existing is false I wanna set lastName and firstName from formgroup as required , it is working but if you look at the image example below when setRequired is executed the is required error is showing without me clicking the input field. The Last name is required for example should only show if setRequired is called and user touch or click the for example lastname field. Any idea guys ? I really need help on this one. Appreciated. Thank you.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsx1P.png)

```
    getStarted(isExisting: boolean) { 
     if(isExisting === false) {
}
    this.setRequired ()
    }


ngOnInit(): void {
  this.initFormGroup();
}
```

#ts code

```
initFormGroup() {
  this.modelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [this.model.id || 0],
    emailAddress: [this.model.emailAddress, Validators.required],
    firstName: this.model.firstName,
    roleId: this.model.roleId,
    lastName: this.model.lastName,
  });

}
```

```
setRequired {
    this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required)
 

}
  if () {
    this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required)
    this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators(Validators.required)
  }
```

#html

```html
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="lastName">
    <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('lastName').hasError('required') && isExisting === false">
      Last name is required.
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want those fields to be required if they are clicked or touched? Why can´t be `required` from the beginning?

Comment: I think what you probably want is the validation all the time, but the message only when the field is touched

Comment: @Andres2142 , i have a feature in my app that user can select 2 options if he wanted to provide a last name , if he clck option 1 last name is required , if he click option 2 last name is not required.

Answer (score 0):

**To make the validation error for "Last name"and "first name" appear only when the user interacts with the field and setRequired is called.We can use the touched and dirty**

```
#html
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="lastName">
  <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('lastName').hasError('required') && modelForm.get('lastName').touched">
    Last name is required.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
  <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
  <mat-error *ngIf="modelForm.get('firstName').hasError('required') && modelForm.get('firstName').touched">
    First name is required.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>


#ts code

initFormGroup() {
  this.modelForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: [this.model.id || 0],
    emailAddress: [this.model.emailAddress, Validators.required],
    firstName: [this.model.firstName], 
    roleId: this.model.roleId,
    lastName: [this.model.lastName], 
  });
}


setRequired() {
  this.modelForm.get('firstName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
  this.modelForm.get('lastName').setValidators([Validators.required]);
  this.modelForm.get('companyName').setValidators([Validators.required]);


  this.modelForm.get('firstName').markAsUntouched();
  this.modelForm.get('lastName').markAsUntouched();
  this.modelForm.get('companyName').markAsUntouched();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a customValidator "requiredIf". The problem with a validator is that can access to the variables of the components else you don't "bind" the function.

That's if you write

```
  required:boolean=false;
  requireIf(required:boolean){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
         return  (required && !control.value)? {required:true}:null
    }
  }
```

And

```
  control=new FormControl('',this.requireIf(this.required))
```

The validator **not change** If we change the variable "this.required"

Well, if you have a variable that not belong to the formGroup "required" that you control with a `[(ngModel)]` you can write the customValidator like

```
  required:boolean=false;
  requireIf(){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
         return  (this.required && !control.value)? {required:true}:null
    }
  }
```

When you create the formGroup (I use the cosntructor of formGroup but be free to use FormBuilder

```
  //pay attention to the "bind(this)" at end of the function
  form=new FormGroup({
    control:new FormControl('',this.requireIf().bind(this))
  })
```

Then we can use in a form like (I don't use the mat-input and mat-formField)

```
<!--see how we "split" [(ngModel)] in [ngModel] and (ngModelChange)
        also you use [value] -not only value- to makes the variable
        get the value true/false boolean, else it get the value 
        "true"/"false" -strings-
-->
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="required" [value]="true"
    [ngModel]="required"
    (ngModelChange)="required=$event;form.controls.control.updateValueAndValidity()"
  />Control required
</label>
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="required" [value]="false"
    [ngModel]="required"
    (ngModelChange)="required=$event;form.controls.control.updateValueAndValidity()"
  />Control not required
</label>

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="control" />
  <div *ngIf="form.controls.control.touched && 
              form.hasError('required','control')"
  >
    required
  </div>
</form>
```

See that we need that, when the "radio buttons" change, we need call to `form.controls.control.updateValueAndValidity()`

NOTE: when use a mat-form-field, the mat-error, by defect, only is show when the control is touched and have error, so you can simply write

```
<mat-form-field ...>
  <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
  <input matInput formControlName="firstName">
  <!--see that you needn't use any contition-->
  <mat-error>
    First name is required.
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-puzrxf?file=src%2Fmain.ts)